# Ошибка TypeError: is undefined

Tags: javascript

Почему `col[y] undefined`, он ведь был создан и сразу к нему присвоено значение?

```js
let col = {};
let y = 0;
col[y].price = col[y].vol = 0;

console.log( col );
```

Comment: "он ведь был создан" - где?

Comment: Может надо было `col = [{}]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
let col = {};
let y = 0;
col[y] = {}; // <---
col[y].price = col[y].vol = 0;

console.log( col );
```